# Matching everything except beginning duplicate letters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match words but without the first or all duplicate letters at the beginning Ex:

`AADBE -> match: DBE`

`AAADKER -> match: DKER`

`DDDDDDKER -> match: KER`

`ADEDE -> match: DEDE`

I tried to use look-behind but for some reason the prioritization doesn't work correctly and it's quite far of:

`/(?<=\s(\2([A-Z])|[A-Z]))[A-Z]+/`

There's probably a much easier way to do this.

Comment: If your input is always like this, another way to think of: [`([A-Z])(?!\1)([A-Z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/LAqH0Y/1) but I'd prefer 4th Birds accurate way myself as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 2 capture groups, and the value is in capture group 2.

```
\b([A-Z])\1*([A-Z]+)\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `([A-Z])\1*` Capture **group 1**, match a single char A-Z and optionally repeat the char that is captured in group 1 using a backreference `\1`
- `([A-Z]+)` Capture **group 2**, repeat 1+ times a char A-Z
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BtG2MI/1)

Comment: If your regex engine supports lookbehind, you can enclose the beginning \b([A-Z])\1* in a lookbehind group and then you don't need the second capturing group - the whole string is matched.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
^([A-Z])\1*
```

with an empty string.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/wC5nTq/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1*                      what was matched by capture \1 (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
```